# Python min and max functions, but with indices

Tags: python, max, minimum

Does Python have a built-in function like min() and max() except that it returns the index rather than the item?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no inbuilt function for that. You can just do `your_list.index(min(your_list))`.

Answer (score 5):

There's no builtin, but `min` and `max` take a `key` argument, which lets you do something like this:

```
from operator import itemgetter

index, elem = min(enumerate(iterable), key=itemgetter(1))
```

This works for any iterable, not just lists.

Comment: Nice answer, but the `index()` method in the currently accepted one handles any sequence type (`str`, `unicode`, `list`, `tuple`, `bytearray`, `buffer`, `xrange` in Python 2.x), which is likely generic enough for most purposes, I suspect.

Comment: I really like this, and I thought it would be faster, as it only has to iterate the list once, whereas `lst.index(min(lst))` has to iterate twice. But even on large (10,000 element) lists, timeit tells me index+min is about twice as fast. :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you have NumPy, it has `argmax` and `argmin` functions you can use.

Answer (score 0):

`min` has a `key=` argument, you can try something like

```
min(range(len(mylist)), key=mylist.__getitem__)
```